# Country Codes to Country Names conversion

Tags: c#, mobile, country

I'm building the registration part of a mobile site and I need to retrieve the country name from the country code of a mobile phone number (eg. +1 corresponds to United States).

Is there any publicly available code/database that will have this info.

Ive tried searching but all I come up with is the conversion of country prefixes to country names (us-United States).

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really programming related, but as always [Wikipedia is your friend](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_country_calling_codes#Complete_Listing).

Wikipedia also links to [this page at the International Telecommunication Union (ITU)](http://www.itu.int/publ/T-SP-E.164D-2009/en).

Answer (score 0):

[Country codes](http://www.the-acr.com/codes/cntrycd.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, [there is](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_country_calling_codes), but it's slightly involved (well, not that hard really).

You'll just need to look up in the order of 1-digit prefix, 2-digit prefix, 3-digit prefix, etc, in order to get the match done correctly (at least, I think so).

Make sure you write a nice test suite for it :) Have fun.